# jquery keypress: trigger click when ctl+x and ctl+s

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, onkeypress, jquery-1.9

I am trying to update and close a popup by using keypress.

if keypress - **ctl+s** = save

if keypress - **ctl+x** = exit

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {

    if ((event.which == 120 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 19)){
    $(".ps-button-close",object_popup).click();
    //alert("Keys down are Ctrl + x + Return");
} else if((event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 19)) {
    // Trigger click.
    ("form.ps-item-form.page input[type=submit][name=update]",object_popup).click();
} else {
    return true;
}

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

But they don't work at all...

Any ideas how I can combine them perfectly?

**edit:**

seems to get them worked now...

```
if ((event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 19)) {

                                        // Trigger click.
                                        $("form.ps-item-form.page input[type=submit][name=update]",object_popup).click();

                                    } else if ((event.which == 120 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 19)){

                                        // Trigger click.
                                        $(".ps-button-close",object_popup).click();
                                        //alert("Keys down are Ctrl + x + Return");

                                    } else {
                                        return true;
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $("form input[type=submit] [name=update]").trigger('click');
```

Comment: i don't think it will work because input element cannot have child elements